# select_layout implementation Ruby meta programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, programming-languages, metaprogramming

How to implement "select_layout" method so that I can transform this code:

```
class Cpu::ContextsController < Cpu::ApplicationController

  layout :select_layout

  private

  def has_resource?
    true # dummy
  end

  def select_layout
    has_resource? ? 'cpu/context' : 'cpu/account'
  end
end
```

into

```
class Cpu::ContextsController < Cpu::ApplicationController
  select_layout do
    has_resource? ? 'cpu/context' : 'cpu/account'
  end
end
```

**UPDATE: solution below is good enough ;)**

```
  before_filter do
    self.class.send(:layout, has_resource? ? 'cpu/context' : 'cpu/account')
  end
```

Comment: what makes you implement metaprogramming here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `render ..., :layout => has_resource? ? "cpu/context" : "cpu/account"` if you want to change layout on the fly, `layout` is a class method and used to specify layout for the set of methods.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find has_resource, because has_resource is defined as an instance method and the select_layout method is defined as a class-method.

Comment: Just define has_resource this method in controller and make it return true

Comment: you'd have to define "self.has_resource" in the controller to make it work.